# Тыкаю или тычу?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: "я тыкаю пальцем" или "я тычу пальцем"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пальцем - тычу. От тыкать - втыкать, вонзать, указывать пальцем и т.д.
Тыкаю - языком. От тыкать - говорить ты.

Я ориентируюсь на Аванесова:
ТЫКАТЬ, тычу, тычешь и доп. тыкаю, тыкаешь... (несов. к ткнуть)
ТЫКАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; (говорить ты вместо вы)

[Тут](http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0591.htm)

Comment: Хотя в речи "Ты мне не тычь" - слышала. Это неверно? Надо "Ты мне не тыкай?"

Comment: В зачении "не говори ты"? Неверно. Но общепринято.

Понимаете, тут тот самый случай, когда три словаря имеют четыре попарно взаимоисключающих мнения.

Лопатин:
тыкать, -аю, -ает (говорить "ты")
тыкать, тычу, тычет и тыкаю, тыкает (к ткнуть)

Кузнецов:
ТЫКАТЬ, тычу, тычешь и -аю, -аешь; тыча и тыкая; нсв.
ТЫКАТЬ, -аю, -аешь и тычу, тычешь; нсв. (кого, кому). Разг.

Зарва:
тыкать, тыкаю, тыкаешь;пов. (не) тыкай (говорить «ты» вместо «вы»)

Я ориентируюсь на Аванесова (см. текст ответа). Лопатин, ксати, ближе всех к нему.

Comment: Спасибо! Особенно за ОНлайн-словарь  Аванесова.У меня такая книга. Но частенько кто-нибудь берет из кабинета и не сразу возвращает. Теперь  всегда могу заглянуть!

Comment: Да я сам без него скучаю. Обидно только, что копипастить нельзя оттуда.